# How to store and get a pointer reference in a global scope in GO

Tags: go

I have got the follow code:

```
package main


func main() {
    // create  a pointer referece of session of Mongo DB
session := mongoDB.CreateSession()

    // Question 1 : How to store a pointer reference in a global scope and using anywhere of the code  

defer session.Close()

    // Note I suppose that the code call to handler methods that call to the Process in the package controller(the last one code)

}
```

Code of creating a session of MongoDB

```
package mongoDB


func CreateSession() *mgo.Session {
session, err := mgo.Dial("192.168.0.108:27017/databasename")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
return session
}
```

Place where I want to use the pointer reference that was store in the main

```
package controller


func Process()  {

    // Question 2 : How can a get the pointer reference store in Question 1 if is posible
collection := mongoDB.CreateCollection(session, "namedatabase", "colectionData")
mongoDB.InsertData(collection, "Ale", "45646565")

}
```

The idea is to avoid passing by reference   **session**(my pointer reference in the main function) in every one of the functions created for all the project.

Comment: Declare your `session` in global scope like `var session <whatever type sessions is>` and use this global. Dead simple, not worth an answer.

Comment: @Volker but if i declate session like    var session <whatever type sessions is>, how can I access from another package diferent of main.

Comment: Any identifier that is uppercase will be exported and therefore visible to other packages.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo like you said is if declare 'var session <whatever type sessions is>' in the package main, so from package controller I can import the package main. How can I do that?.

Comment: You can't because it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have your `controller` package import `main`. That is not a good idea (and I am quite sure it is not even possible). But that doesn't mean you can't have a global `session` variable in the `controller`.

You can try this:

```
package main

import (
    "controller"
    "mongoDB"
)

func main() {
    // create  a pointer referece of session of Mongo DB
    session := mongoDB.CreateSession()
    defer session.Close()

    controller.SetDBSession(session) // Or controller.Init or whatever you like

    controller.Process()
}
```

And then in the `controller` package you have:

```
package controller

import "mongoDB"

// Global session var for the package
var session mongoDB.Session

// SetDBSession sets the mongoDB session to be used by the controller package.
// This function must be called before calling Process()
func SetDBSession(s mongoDB.Session) {
    session = s
}

func Process() {
    collection := mongoDB.CreateCollection(session, "namedatabase", "colectionData")
    mongoDB.InsertData(collection, "Ale", "45646565")
}
```

Using this solution, you will only have to pass the session to the controller package once, letting main take care of the creating and closing of the session.